# How can I set up Postfix so that all email sent on my dev box gets routed to the developer email group?

Tags: postfix

I have a development server, and at the moment email is disabled on it, so we can do whatever we need to with the system without worrying about accidentally emailing clients' customers.

I'd like to set up Postfix (or something similar) to route all email from that machine to a specific, single address, no matter who it is addressed to or which domain name they are using.

I've tried this, with no success (the BCC works, but the email still goes to the original recipient):

```
local_recipient_maps =
luser_relay = development@domain.com
always_bcc = development@domain.com
```

I'm using Ubuntu server 10.04, pretty standard LAMP setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to do address mapping in the canonical table. Add the following to /etc/postfix/canonical:

```
/^.*$/   your@address.com
```

and run postmap afterwards

```
postmap canonical
```

This should do it.

Comment: I'm probably doing this wrong, but I didn't get very far. There was no /etc/postfix/canonical file, so I created one with the text above. I then ran "postmap canonical", but got this error: "postmap: fatal: open canonical: No such file or directory"

Comment: Before running "postmap canonical" cd into /etc/postfix or run "postmap /etc/postfix/canonical" .

Comment: Also, in /etc/postfix/main.cf you should have a line "canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical" .

Comment: All sorted - thanks rems! I had a couple of issues, which I'll outline here in case anyone else comes looking for this. I didn't realise what postmap was doing, first. So to do the above, I created a text file (/etc/postfix/canonical) with the first line from rems. I then ran postmap from the postix directory, and that generated a database file used by postfix (canonical.db). The line added to main.cf doesn't use the .db extension, but does look for the .db file. Finally you need regexp: instead of hash: if using a regex pattern as above.

Comment: ups, sorry, yes, it should have been a "regexp:" not a "hash:". I did copy & paste from the wrong main.cf.