# Exim4 intercept all outgoing mail

Tags: php, debian, email-server, exim, lamp

I have a LAMP stack set up on a Debian 8 (jessie) machine. I'm trying to find a way of intercepting all outgoing mail sent by PHP (through sendmail) and instead of sending it out, deliver it to my local inbox (to the local user). I don't want to send anything to the outside world, I only want to be able to see the content of a message through my terminal.

I know that [this](https://serverfault.com/a/234347) works with Postfix, but I can't install Postfix on my machine because it conflicts with Exim4 and I don't want to make too many changes to my dev. server.

Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the router that redirect outgoing messages:

```
intercept:
  driver          = redirect
  domains         = !+local_domains
  data            = auditor@local.tld
  pipe_transport  = address_pipe
  no_more
```

Place that router at the very beginning of `begin routers` section to ensure each message will be proceeded. When message addressed to the outer domains fall into that router, it will replace original recipient(s) with `auditor@local.tld`. You can also implement white/black lists of recipients that will be checked by router. Say, if recipient belongs to the white list, then message will not be intercepted while all other will be.